# Query not inserting to database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to insert to my database. I have tried pasting the query into MySQL Workbench and it works, but when I run the page it doesn't work.

```
echo "<b>DISTRICT</b></br>";
echo "crime volume : " . $crimeVolume. "<br>";
echo "population : " . $population. "<br>";
echo "crime rate : " . $crimeRate=round(($crimeVolume/($population/100000)),2) . " <br>";
echo "crime efficiency / crime clearance efficiency : " . $efficiency=($SolvedCases/$crimeVolume) ." <br>";
echo "use of force : " . $useofForce . " incidents<br>";
echo "drug seizures : " . $numdrug . " (grams/seizures)<br>";
echo "firearm seizures : " . $firearmSeizures=round(($numfire/$stationFire),2) . " <br>";
echo "<br>";
require_once('../../mysqlConnector/mysql_connect.php');
$query2= "INSERT INTO computation (crimeVolume,crimeRate,crimeSolutionEfficiency,useofForce,drugSeizures,firearmsSeizures,stationID) 
VALUES ('{$crimeVolume}','{$crimeRate}','{$efficiency}','{$useofForce}','{$numdrug}','{$firearmSeizures}','0');";
echo $query2;
$result=mysqli_query($dbc,$query2);
echo $result;
```

Comment: Where is $dbc coming from ? Can you post the full code please ?

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will also fix any pesky quoting issues you may have.** This would be a good place to check for [mysqli_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: <?php
$dbc=mysqli_connect('localhost','username','password','database');

if (!$dbc) {
 die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
}


?>

this is the $dbc!

Comment: You can't use `mysql_error()` with mysqli. It doesn't mix. And you should get the error coming from `mysqli_error($dbc)` instead. And you can't echo `$result`, it's an object. And finally, what is `echo $query2;` outputting?

Comment: did you get any error? Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);`on top of page just after `<?php`  and change the line like this:-  `$result=mysqli_query($dbc,$query2) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));`  and check

Comment: @Alive to Die, i tried but no error came out!

Comment: What if you add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` after creating the SQL connection (where you define `$dbc`)? And are you sure you connect properly? (Do `var_dump($dbc)`)

Answer (score -1):

Please try this example, by setting your database connection details and it should work flawless.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){ echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); }

// Perform query
$result mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO computation (crimeVolume,crimeRate,crimeSolutionEfficiency,useofForce,drugSeizures,firearmsSeizures,stationID) 
VALUES ('".$crimeVolume."','".$crimeRate."','".$efficiency."','".$useofForce."','".$numdrug."','".$firearmSeizures."','0')");

// Print result
print_r($result);

// Close connection
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Note that this is not the final solution, you are better off using a proper CLASS that has some filtering and error checking as well. ( why not a framework ? ).

I hope it helps your case.

Comment: Turn the tide against teaching/propagating sloppy and dangerous coding practices. If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).